# Making my php pages search engine friendly

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

In my site,  I have used mod rewrite to make search engine and user friendly urls.

Only 3 rules:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=articles&cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=articles&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But index.php is still accessible by anyone and will work even if a friendly URL is not used(that is, instead parameters are passed).
So, does this down rank by search engine ? Do I have to block direct access to files with `.php` extension ?

Comment: if you can give the code, we could understand what's going on. Paste your .htaccess here

Comment: thanku. I had updated above post by replacing it with rules

Comment: One option would be: inside index.php check if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is the SEO-friendly URL, and if not, send a 301 redirect to it. That will force browsers to use the URL without any need to hide or block the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 URLs that load the same page where one is search engine friendly and the other is not, this is not really detrimental to your site AFAIK.  Basically you just want to expose to search engines as much as you can, so if you need to provide a parallel track, for example an anchor tag that works fine without Javascript because the action will take you to the correct place (which is ideal for a bot) but typically is managed by Javascript for clients that have it (most standard web browsers) then you're golden.

EDIT:

Per OP question in a comment about parallel paths..  Say I have a link, an anchor tag.

```
<a id="moxune_services" href="http://moxune.com/services" action="get" target="_self">Moxune Services</a>
```

You can see that this is a valid link (and I will be getting SEO points for it from StackOverflow ;P  But anyway, say this is part of a heave JS driven site, and rather than refreshing the whole page when this link is clicked, I just want to have a subsection of the page like where a **div** w/ *id="content"* is present be replaced by the fresh content after I have AJAX load it.  The js would be *something* like this (w/o testing, this is just off the top of my head) (a jQuery solution as well):

```
// very crude jQuery example!
$('#moxune_services').click(function() {
  $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(sNewHtml) {
    $('#content').replaceWith(sNewHtml);
  });
});
```

Now you see, the google bot can reach the page through the HTML a tag, no problem, but your customers looking for a Web 2.0 (TM) website will be able to enjoy the lack of full page refreshes as they have JS enabled (and hopefully aren't using IE 6 :O).

One term for this is 'graceful degradation'.

Comment: thanku. I heard someone saying that it would create negative reputation by search engines. So you are saying there is no problem. Isn't it ?

Comment: No there is no problem.  Search engines will not doc you for things which they do not understand.  The idea is not to have to create parallel paths if you can avoid it, but in JS heavy sites, sometimes you have to deal w/ this if much of the content is publicly exposed.

Comment: thanku. can u please give me example of that "parallel paths" that you said above?

Answer (score 0):

quickshiftin is right here. There's no point hiding the index.php

If you must, however do this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php.+$ / [L,R=301]
```

I didn't test this, so it might not work, but the general idea is to  redirect index.php to /